# How to determine if laptop motherboard is dead

Tags: laptop, motherboard, dell-latitude

My laptop Dell Latitude E5530 just suddenly stopped working. 2 days ago I turned it off (put it in sleep mode) and yesterday afternoon when I went to turn it on I get a black screen.

First thing which comes to mind is the battery. I plugged the charger in for about 2h but nothing happened. I heard that the cooler works, but nothing shows up on the monitor.

I took out my HDD and formatted it and put it back but again but nothing happened.

I tried another charger from another Dell which is compatible but againg no result

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96340/discussion-on-question-by-robby-how-to-determine-if-laptop-motherboard-is-dead).